# Solve the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1} + 6a_{n-2} + 5\cdot3^n\; \forall n\geq 2\;\;a_0=4\;\; a_1=6$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

> Solve the recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1} + 6a_{n-2} + 5\cdot3^n\; \forall n\geq
>  2\;\;a_0=4\;\; a_1=6$

I let $$g(x)=\sum_{i\geq 0} a_i x^i$$

Using this I was able to obtain

$$g(x)=\frac{39x^2-10x+4}{(3x-1)^2(2x+1)}$$

Now I want the coefficient of $x^n$ in my $g(x)$ which will equal $a^n$. So how do I get this? Also if possible, please verify my $g(x)$ is correct or not. I was searching for online tool to do same, but can't find one

Comment: According to Wolframalpha, it is $$a_n = \dfrac{1}{5} 3^n (15 n +5) + 3 (-2)^n$$ [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%28n%29+%3D+a%28n-1%29%2B6*a%28n-2%29%2B5*3%5En%2C+a%280%29%3D4%2C+a%281%29%3D6)

Comment: And here is the Series Expansion of $g(x)$, which gives the exact same $a_n$, implying your choice of $g(x)$ was correct: [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B%2839x%5E2-10x%2B4%29%2F%28%283x-1%29%5E2%282x%2B1%29%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2Cn%7D%5D)

Comment: Do you know partial fraction decomposition? If so, after the decomposition, the method to obtain the coefficients can be done by binomial expansion of the denominator.

Comment: Yes I know partial fraction decomposition but it was getting messy. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing partial fraction decomposition on $g(x)$, we obtain $\frac{3}{1 + 2 x} + \frac{3}{(-1 + 3 x)^2} + \frac{2}{(-1 + 3 x)}$.

Applying Taylor series expansion on the denominator, we obtain

\begin{align}\frac{3}{1 + 2 x} + \frac{2}{(-1 + 3 x)}+ \frac{3}{(-1 + 3 x)^2} &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (3\cdot(-2)^n+(-2)3^n+)x^n+3^n(3n+3))x^n\\\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty 3^n(3n+1)+3\cdot(-2)^nx^n
\end{align}

Therefore, you get $a_n= 3^n(3n+1)+3\cdot(-2)^n$